# How to communicate from Android smartphone with Java program using Bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I would like to create a Java desktop application and an Android application so that they can communicate with each other using Bluetooth.

Any recommendations on where I should start from?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could checkout the [bluecove](http://code.google.com/p/bluecove/) java library. It seems fairly mature and well documented. The [javax.bluetooth](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr082/javax/bluetooth/package-summary.html) package is also included with most standard java platforms.

Answer (score 0):

It goes without saying, but you'll want to start looking at the [Android Bluetooth DevGuide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html) early on too.